# how to use functions from installed packages in VUE 3 composition API

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm struggling to understand how to use functions in Vue 3 from 3rd party JavaScript libraries. I am trying to use the interactive fiction library inkjs in my Vue 3 project. I installed it using: npm install inkjs. I am using the composition API. However, I cannot access the functions in inkjs. Specifically, this does not work:

```
import { ref } from '@vue/reactivity'
import getStory from '../ink/story.js'
import { inkjs } from 'inkjs' 

export default {
  name: 'HomeView',
  setup() {

    const { storyContent } = getStory()
    const story = new inkjs.Story(storyContent.value)

    return { displayText, story }
  }
}
```

Story is the main function in the inkjs library.
It gives this console error:

```
HomeView.vue?43d0:29 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Story')
    at setup (HomeView.vue?43d0:29:1)
    at callWithErrorHandling (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:155:1)
    at setupStatefulComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:7160:1)
    at setupComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:7114:1)
    at mountComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:5468:1)
    at processComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:5443:1)
    at patch (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:5033:1)
    at ReactiveEffect.componentUpdateFn [as fn] (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:5655:1)
    at ReactiveEffect.run (reactivity.esm-bundler.js?89dc:185:1)
    at instance.update (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:5689:1)
```

Comment: This means that the package doesn't have inkjs named export. Check its usage

Comment: As @EstusFlask suggested, try using the default export:
import inkjs from 'inkjs'